# WPF: Textbox and Binding to Double not able to type . on it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a text box like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TransactionDetails.TransactionAmount, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" 
x:Name="TextBoxAmount"/>
```

And I have taken "TransactionAmount" as Double. Its working well on integer value but when I am typing some Floating point value like 100.456 I am not able to type '.'

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. Can you add just enough code so I can try it?

Comment: The TransactionDetails is my enyity and TransactionAmount is the property of my entity like
private double _transactionAmount;
public double TransactionAmount
        {
            get { return _transactionAmount; }
            set { _transactionAmount = value; Notify("TransactionAmount"); }
        }

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. Please get my code and try it out in a new project: http://pastebin.com/yVPCKG30

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger= LostFocus didnt help?

Comment: I checked it but still I am not able to type 1.75 in the textbox.I mean not able to type floating point number

Comment: Very strange since I can enter 1.75. Glad you got an answer you accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I got by using `StringFormat` like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TransactionDetails.TransactionAmount, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat=N2}" Grid.Column="3" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5" x:Name="TextBoxAmount" />
```

Also we can go for custom string format as per requirements

Answer (score 17):

You are updating your property every time the value changes. When you type in a `.`, it is written into your viewmodel and the view is updated.

e.g. if you type in `100.` it is rounded to `100`, thus you won't see any dot ever.

You have some options to change this behavior:

use a deferred binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TransactionDetails.TransactionAmount, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        Delay=250}" 
         Grid.Column="3" 
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
         Grid.Row="5" 
         x:Name="TextBoxAmount" />
```

only change the value if it is different from the saved one
(I'd recommend this for every binding):

```
private double _transactionAmount; 
public double TransactionAmount  
{
  get { return _transactionAmount; }    
  set
  { 
    if (_transactionAmount != value)
    {
      _transactionAmount = value; 
      Notify("TransactionAmount"); 
    }
  }
```

or use some kind of validation, e.g. ValidatesOnExceptions.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I really like it! Ran into this issue before and never found the proper solution (your second proposal!). If I can suggest a few edits: 1) Get rid of the deferred binding, that's really tricky. I can manage to change a value on my keyboard and click an OK button within that timeframe. 2) I had to change the mode to `Mode=OneWayToSource` in order to get your second solution to work. 3) Double comparison without epsilon is not really cool ;-). Maybe change that with `Math.Abs(value - _transactionAmount) > 0.000001`.

Comment: For me, this looks more like a workaround. I found that the answer given by Jonas Marty works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388021/1520078

Answer (score 6):

The behavior is as expected when your app targets .NET 4.0 or earlier but was changed later on ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkcompatibilitypreferences.keeptextboxdisplaysynchronizedwithtextproperty?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks)). The old behavior can be restored by setting:

```
System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
```

Set this as early as possible (e.g. in the constructor of App.cs), otherwise the framework raises an exception.

Source and detailed explanation: https://web.archive.org/web/20220127083119/https://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1855

Comment: Actually, this answer must be accepted.

Comment: While updating an old application to a more recent .NET Framework, this solution worked for me!

Comment: And this is why you should actually copy/summarize the detailed explanation instead of just linking it; the link is dead now.

Comment: I replaced the dead link with a link to the waybackmachine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is with UpdateSourceTrigger. 
Instead of using there You can use something like this,

```
private double amount;
public double Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return amount;
        }
        set
        {
            amount= value;
            PropertyChanged();
            Calculation();
        }
    }
```

PropertyChanged() You will get this from INotifyPropertyChanged. For more Information click here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If I am deleting "UpdateSourceTrigger" my Notify is not working. On which I am doing some mathematical calculation

Comment: Notify will trigger only after the text box lostfocus.

Comment: Actually I have multiple textboxes.On property changed of every textboxes I am calculating addition and percentages

Comment: You can do your calculation in setter of the property. after property changed You can call your calculation method inside setter itself. I updated that in answer

Answer (score 1):

In binding of the property use, `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`. It will update the property once textbox is out of focus.

Comment: Nice option to the obscure app-wide property given in another answer here. I'm kind of scared of app-wide properties altering defaults in our 100K+ lines of code enterprise application. The textbox should always lose focus at one point or another anyway, even if you don't tab out of the textbox before clicking OK.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the default converter with this class when binding to double type source data. This is more convient to use. below is the code:

```
public class double2txtConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        string _strCache;
        double _dCache;
        //Convert double to string of textbox.
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (_dCache == (double)value)
                return _strCache;
            else
                return value.ToString();
        }
        //convert string to double;
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            _strCache = (string)value;
            _dCache = double.Parse(_strCache);
            return _dCache;
        }
    }
//below is codebehind usage:
        Binding bd = new Binding(path);
        bd.Converter = new double2txtConverter();
        bd.Source = source;
        bd.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        txtTarget.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving answer based on the answer of Herm above. The explanation is correct, but using `Delay` on control won't solve the issue fully. If the end user types 0.005, the delay required will be more, otherwise it will re-write value as 0.

Instead, Use a string property for binding and try to parse it to double and based on parse output set the long value you need. Put all kind of validations you need before setting the value

```
private double _amount;
private string _amountString;
public string Amount
{
    get { return _amountString;}
    set {
            double d=0;
            if(Double.TryParse(value, out d))
            {
                _amountString=value;
                _amount=d;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by additonal property.

```cs
    public class DoubleTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public string DoubleText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DoubleTextProperty);
            set => SetValue(DoubleTextProperty, value);
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DoubleTextProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register(
                  nameof(DoubleText),
                  typeof(string),
                  typeof(DoubleTextBox),
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                      string.Empty,
                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDoubleTextChanged),
                      null,
                      true,
                      UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus));
    
        private static void OnDoubleTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is TextBox textBox)
            {
                var currentText = textBox.Text;
                var newText = (string)e.NewValue;
                if (currentText == newText)
                    return;
                if (
                    double.TryParse(currentText, out var currentDouble) &&
                    double.TryParse(newText, out var newDouble) &&
                    currentDouble == newDouble
                    )
                    return;
    
                textBox.Text = newText;
            }
        }
    
        protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
            this.DoubleText = this.Text;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```xml
<myControl:DoubleTextBox DoubleText="{Binding Double1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```